# Unable to resolve Microsoft.AspNet.RequestContainer >= 1.0.0-beta4-11232

Tags: asp.net-core

In my project I am installing Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer 1.0.0-beta4-11758 and it continues to say it can't find a reference to dependency Microsoft.AspNet.RequestContainer >= 1.0.0-beta4-11232

Now I can't find that reference anywhere, even in the nightly builds.

Is anyone able to help with what is going on here. I can't use beta3 at the moment because my DNX and other packages required are beta4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally found out the issue, more namespace changes happened. I suppose you get that in beta releases.

I should be using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer not Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer. It looks like the Security namespace has changed across the board.

To help others find these kinds of issues look at the nightly build page

https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext

Switch between the master and the dev version to note changes.

Comment: I'd also recommend watching https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/labels/Breaking%20change for breaking changes!

Comment: Got me out of downward troubleshooting spiral.  Thanks.